# Returning values from INDEX based on matching value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to build a sheet that shows a report of student attendance on a given day.  Below is an example that will return the required data but not based on the current day - today().  I'm struggling to think of a way to do this with my current formula.  Perhaps on the wrong path?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXiXE45plIQb88pORGT9qZLcW-AADEDyRp4bLY2Uh8c/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter (based on today and value 'P ) try:

```
=query({$A$2:$A, filter($A$2:$D,$A$1:$D$1=today())}, "select Col1 where Col2 ='"&E$1&"' ", 0)
```

Drag to the right for the other values (A, L).

Also see the hightlighted cells in the sheet you shared.

Hope this helps ?

Comment: This is excellent, I wasn't even aware you could use SQL style "Where" commands in Spreadsheets! Thank you, I should be able to work from this!

Comment: Most welcome. If that helped you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I worked in some of live data to test and made a small change (sheet only shows day number so =day(today()) was added.  For some reason, it won't add up the first set of "Preschool" data and gets confused when looking 'A' ?? 

Any ideas?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXiXE45plIQb88pORGT9qZLcW-AADEDyRp4bLY2Uh8c/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi Gaz, use the optional header argument in the query (set to zero). Also wrap the formula in an iferror() to suppress errors in case nothing is found. See you sheet for the changes.